# writeLines() returns blank .txt after transformation-r tm package

Tags: r, tm

I was creating the corpus and transforming a bunch of `.txt` files using the `tm` package. These `.txt` files contain texts I copied and pasted from web pages. After running the **Corpus** code, I ran the `writeLines(as.character)` function to check on files. However, the return of three `.txt` files were blank.

And then after I transformed the case and punctuations as below, more files were returned as blank.

```
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(...))
docs <-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) { return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "–")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "’")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "'")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ".")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "“")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "”")
writeLines(as.character(docs[[10]]))
```

I wonder if it was an error done by me, or because of some issues with the original `.txt` files?

Comment: `gsub` uses regex so `gsub(".", " ", x)` will replace every character with a space. You need to excape it: `gsub("\\.", " ", x)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed the code for "." to "\\." and it worked!